# How do I get the custom attribute of an "option" tag after firing the "change" event listener?

Tags: javascript, html

**My HTML:**

```
<select>
    <option customAttr="foo">Foo Text</option>
    <option customAttr="bar">Bar Text</option>
</select>
```

**My JS:**

```
selectElement.addEventListener("change",function(){
    console.log(this.getAttribute("customAttr"));
});
```

This only logs `null`. Why? How do I make it log the value of `customAttr`?

Comment: Look at what `this` is. It'll be the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to target the selected option like the following:

```js
var selectElement = document.querySelector('select');
selectElement.addEventListener("change",function(){
  var option = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
  console.log(option.getAttribute("customAttr"));
});
```

```html
<select>
  <option customAttr="foo">Foo Text</option>
  <option customAttr="bar">Bar Text</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also access to your attribute by adding a value in your option tag, like this :

```js
const select = document.getElementById('select');

select.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    const options = select.querySelectorAll("option");
    const item = e.target.value;
    
    console.log(options[item].getAttribute('customAttr'));
});
```

```html
    <select id='select'>
        <option value='0' customAttr="foo">Foo Text</option>
        <option value='1' customAttr="bar">Bar Text</option>
    </select>
```